# how to detect the location of contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

im pretty new with opencv and python in general. and I want to make a program that counts cars with a camera. i've made the program and I have found the contours, but the problem is I don't know how to know the location of the contours exactly where on which lane. i've made an example using paint below [contours on a 4 lane road](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqo0L.png)

on the image above there is 1 car in the north, 2 car in the south, 3 car in the west, and 2 car in the east. i want to know how to detect the contours location. thank you

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import picamera.array
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sign2

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)


cam = PiCamera()
cam.resolution=(480,480)
cam.framerate=30
raw=PiRGBArray(cam, size=(480,480))

time.sleep(0.1)

colorLower = np.array([0,100,100])
colorUpper = np.array([179,255,255])

purplelow = np.array([125,100,100])
purpleup = np.array([136,255,255])

initvert = 0
inithoriz = 0
initverta = 0
inithoriza = 0




for frame in cam.capture_continuous(raw, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    frame = frame.array
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    purplemask = cv2.inRange(hsv,purplelow,purpleup)
    
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,colorLower,colorUpper)
    mask = cv2.blur(mask,(3,3))
    mask= cv2.dilate(mask,None,iterations=5)
    mask= cv2.erode(mask,None,iterations=1)
    mask= cv2.dilate(mask,None,iterations=3)

    purplemask = cv2.inRange(hsv,purplelow,purpleup)
    purplemask = cv2.blur(purplemask,(3,3))
    purplemask= cv2.dilate(purplemask,None,iterations=5)
    purplemask= cv2.erode(purplemask,None,iterations=1)
    purplemask= cv2.dilate(purplemask,None,iterations=3)
    

    
    me,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    me,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(mask,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    center = None
    cnts2 = cv2.findContours(thresh2,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    center = None

    vert = 0
    horiz = 0
    verta = 0
    horiza = 0
```

Comment: could you post the code you are working with as this will make answering your question more likely

Comment: Get the contour bounding box and use either the centroid or upper left corner. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7 and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/

Comment: @DrBwts i have posted the code

Comment: @fmw42 I will read that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the contours & their centroids in your code add the following. A list of the centroids is stored in `centroids`

```
conts, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
centroids = []

for c in conts[0:-1]:       
    x = int(sum(c[:,0,0]) / len(c))
    y = int(sum(c[:,0,1]) / len(c))
    centroids.append([x, y])
    # if you want to display on original image
    cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (255, 255, 0), -1)
```